# Tenacious badge. Does answer still apply if has 1 upvote and 1 downvote

Tags: support, badges, voting

I'm working on getting the tenacious badge ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/225/tenacious)).

> Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total

Will an answer count towards the badge if it has been voted on, but still equals 0 before it's 10 days old? An example would be an answer with 1 upvote and 1 downvote to make it equal to 0. Or will the answer not count towards the badge if it has any votes on it at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the score is 0, then it counts. The logic for this badge does not look at votes at all, just the score of the applicable posts.

Answer (score 4):

All accepted answers will go towards that badge once their score is equal to 0, regardless of previous actions. Just like the badge description, the answers only need to be:

- Accepted
- Has a score of 0

to be able to count towards the badge.